# Android Deep Link doesn't work on lower API version (Android 5.0.2, API 21) but works on API Level 28 (Android 9.0)

Tags: android, hyperlink, manifest

I'll cut to the chase.

The deep linking that I implemented into my application works on my Google Pixel XL running Android 9.0 (API Level 28) but didn't work on Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2. (SM-P905 running API Level 21, Android 5.0.2).

I've made sure to generate an application APK and installed it on both my Pixel XL and the target device (the Samsung tablet) and on my Pixel Xl the deep link feature works perfectly but in the target samsung device the URL when clicked on Chrome wouldn't open my app.

The AndroidManifest.xml that I have is as follow:

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityName"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="hostName.com"
                android:pathPattern="/some/path/pattern.*"/>


    </activity>
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here? Inside build.gradle, this has also been specified:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
}
```

Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: Is application crashing? Have you tried debugging the application on Samsung Note. Kindly update question with few logs

Comment: @ShadowDroid, Nah the application doesn't crash. It's working fine in the samsung tablet. NOW, here's the really tricky part, I don't have the samsung tablet with me. I'm doing this work remotely and that's why I've been using my Pixel XL as a test device :(

Comment: what about emulator ?

Comment: @TejasPandya Yeah I'm testing it right now mate haha, I'll definitely come back here and report it to you guys. This is so weird....

Answer (score 1):

this is a stupid mistake.

Well apparently I forgot to add "www" in front of android:hostname inside AndroidManifest.xml file -_- and that's why it didn't work on the samsung tablet.

The weird thing is, I need to omit the "www" prefix if I want the app to work on my Pixel Xl but on the Samsung tablet I NEED the "www" prefix.

Anyway, this question is closed hahaha, my bad.

Cheers~